# Why doesn't $ in my regex match end of line

Tags: python, regex

I have the following test program:

```
import re

class Test:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.idFiltering = True
        self.aliases = [
            ('rose', 'jasmin')
        ]

        for s in (
            '__rose__',
            'rose',

            'moon__rose',
            'rose__fish',
            'moon__rose__jelly__fish',
            'moon__rose__rose__rose__fish',

            'sun.moon.rose',
            'rose.fish',
            'rosexfish',
            'moon.rose.jelly__fish',

            'moon/rose',
            'rose/fish',
            'moon/rose/jelly__fish',

        ):   
            print (s, self.filterId (s))
        print ('done')

    def filterId (self, qualifiedId):
        if not self.idFiltering or (qualifiedId.startswith ('__') and qualifiedId.endswith ('__')):
            return qualifiedId
        else:        
            for alias in self.aliases:
                pattern = re.compile (rf'((__)|(?=[^./])){alias [0]}((__)|(?=[./$]))')

                # Replace twice to deal with overlap
                qualifiedId = pattern.sub (alias [1], qualifiedId)
                qualifiedId = pattern.sub (alias [1], qualifiedId)

            return qualifiedId

test = Test ()
```

I expect it to produce:

```
__rose__ __rose__
rose jasmin
moon__rose moon__jasmin
rose__fish jasminfish
moon__rose__jelly__fish moonjasminjelly__fish
moon__rose__rose__rose__fish moonjasminjasminjasminfish
sun.moon.rose sun.moon.jasmin
rose.fish jasmin.fish
rosexfish rosexfish
moon.rose.jelly__fish moon.jasmin.jelly__fish
moon/rose moon/jasmin
rose/fish jasmin/fish
moon/rose/jelly__fish moon/jasmin/jelly__fish
done
```

But it produces:

```
__rose__ __rose__
rose rose
moon__rose moon__rose
rose__fish jasminfish
moon__rose__jelly__fish moonjasminjelly__fish
moon__rose__rose__rose__fish moonjasminjasminjasminfish
sun.moon.rose sun.moon.rose
rose.fish jasmin.fish
rosexfish rosexfish
moon.rose.jelly__fish moon.jasmin.jelly__fish
moon/rose moon/rose
rose/fish jasmin/fish
moon/rose/jelly__fish moon/jasmin/jelly__fish
done
```

In other words, it doesn't replace 'rose' at the end of a word.
It seems to ignore the $ in my pattern.
What am I doing wrong?

[EDIT after comments of Aran-Fey and Pushpesh Kumar Rajwanshi]

I've changed the regex to:

```
rf'((__)|(?=[^./])){alias [0]}((__)|(?=[./])|$)'
```

and it works fine now, so my problem is solved.

I've also tried:

```
rf'(^|(__)|(?=[./])){alias [0]}((__)|(?=[./])|$)'
```

but that does not work. Just curious: Why not?

[EDIT2]

As Rarblack pointed out, my solution just worked by sheer luck.
With his/her suggestion I think I found the right regex:

```
rf'(^|(__)|(?<=[./])){alias [0]}((__)|(?=[./])|$)'
```

It produces the expected output, and this time not by coincidence.

Comment: `[$]` is a *character set*. It matches a `$` *character*.

Comment: You need to take it out of character set [./$]. Some special meaning characters when placed within [] character set looses its special meaning

Comment: @Aran-Fey and Pushpesh Kumar Rajwanshi: Your suggestions work fine and my problem is solved.  I've also tried to take the ^ out of the charset, but that doesn't work. Just curious: Any idea why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put special regex attributes in `[]` they lose their meaning and act like ordinary characters. That is why `[./$]` is not working. Also, putting `^` inside square brackets means not to filter through all attributes inside it: `[^./]`.

Comment: So I'm just lucky it works in this case, but my solution isn't a good one. Any idea on how to improve it? EDIT: I think I found it, see second edit to question.